# How can I go to exact position of xml file having its XPath and Offset?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse xml files as ElementTree objects. I'm building annotation application, and I need to reach to exact positions in the file.
I have relative XPath and `startOffset` of where the intended text is located. For example in this piece of code:

```
<section role="doc-abstract">
    <h1>Abstract</h1>
    <p>The creation and use of knowledge graphs for information discovery, question answering, and task completion has exploded in recent years, but their application has often been limited to the most common user scenarios.</p>
</section>
```

I want to get the part "knowledge graphs for information discovery" with following XPath `".//section[2]/p[1]"` so I can get to that `<p>` element. Then I have `startOffset` variable equal to "26" which means the text is 26 characters far from the beginning  of the element.
My question is how can I get to that exact position using lxml?

Comment: Is not it just a slice: `p.text[startOffset:]`?..where `p` is the element you've located?

Comment: Exactly. but that returns a string. I need to create an element at that position, so is there any way to return an Element object so I can use insert() and insert_before() methods?

Comment: OK, I created new Element, and put my text as Element.text, then replaced the actual text with etree.tostring(Element.text) to have that text wrapped in a tag. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your xml to be stored in a string - xml_string.

```
from lxml import etree

#initialize a parser
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
#initialize the xml root, it will automatically take the root of the xml
root = etree.XML(xml_string, parser)
node = root.find('//section[2]/p[1]')
```

Now you can do processing of this node. Also, you can use a loop for finding more node_elements, for eg: root.findall()

For more reference on lxml: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html